# How i can filter messages based on custom data in QuickBlox

Tags: quickblox

I have implemented 1-1 chat in QuickBlox Chat and sending some custom data via custom parameters. Is it possible to filter the chat messages based on these custom parameters while fetching the records?

Answer (score 0):

You can not get filter base messages, but you can get filter base dialogs.
look at here :

```
var filters = {"sort_desc": "last_message_date_sent"} ;

QB.chat.dialog.list(filters, function(err, resDialogs) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {

  }
});
```

Hope this will help you.